Can't access install button on AccessibilityEvent when using Package Installer
I use the AccessibilityService on Android to automatically install apps. It worked fine with versions up to Android 13. However, with the new Android 14.
I've run into the problem that the AccessibilityEvent and nodes do not contain the Install button, when try to find it using nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Installieren") - the text that contains the String "Installieren" is found, but not the button. Here's a picture of the event with its containing text — there is no install-text.
Event with Dialog next to it
My code that worked until Android 14 looks like this:
private boolean handlePackageInstallerEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (isWindowStateChgEvent(event)
            && event.getPackageName()!= null
            && PACKAGE_PACKAGEINSTALLER.equals(event.getPackageName().toString())) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
        if (nodeInfo != null) {
        
            // More code ...
            
            if (childNodeInfos.isEmpty()) {
                // Check for installation case
                // Issue: does not find any Button with text "Installieren" from Android 14!
                childNodeInfos = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Installieren");
            }
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo childNodeInfo : childNodeInfos) {
                if (childNodeInfo.getClassName().toString().contains("Button")) {
                    CharSequence text = childNodeInfo.getText();
                    boolean clickable = childNodeInfo.isClickable();
                    boolean enabled = childNodeInfo.isEnabled();
                    childNodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Even if I manually navigate through the tree, I can't find the Install button. I tried a little trick and activated the Accessibility Service in the phone settings so it would read the text "Installieren" as audio output and highlights it with a border: it seems to be there.
When I manually click the install button, i do not receive an AccessibilityEvent (as something like BorderChangeEvent).
However, when I listen for the hover event and hover over the Install button with my mouse, I finally get a button, but its text is empty and it has the same ID as the Cancel button.
Is it a new safety measure I am not aware of? I already checked for new permissions that I might need to add, but there are none.
